# How to sort Object mapping in Javascript in descending order of VALUES?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, mapping

I have an Object map of account numbers and balances.

```
Balance: {
"a": "1000"
"b": "3000"
"c": "2000"
}
```

How do I sort this balance by descending order by balance amount so it becomes:

```
Balance: {
"b": "3000"
"c": "2000"
"a": "1000"
}
```

Comment: It already is sorted that way. Properties are always ordered in ascending numeric order, for array indicies

Comment: it is sorted by key but i want it to be sorted by value

Comment: Object properties *are* ordered.

Comment: i just changed the example to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are not ordered. It is meaningless to try to "sort" them. If you want to sort an object by its values, you can sort the keys by values, and then retrieve the associated values like the below example.

```js
var myObj = {
    'b': 3000,
    'c': 1000,
    'a': 2000
  },
  keys = Object.keys(myObj),
  i, len = keys.length;

keys.sort((a, b) => myObj[a] < myObj[b] ? 1 : -1);

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  k = keys[i];
  console.log(k + ':' + myObj[k]);
}
```

Comment: Objects *are* ordered in modern JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58444013 but it's a code smell to rely on them